# Where statement cancels out results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find `UID` numbers from the below sample that meet a contradicting where statement but is true. The idea is to prove that an 'open' & 'child' cannot exist if the 'parent' & 'closed is in the data. The sample below should return `UID=789` as a use case error.

```
UID     Title   Business
123     Parent  Open
123     Child 1 Open
123     Child 2 Open
456     Parent  Closed
456     Child 1 Closed
456     Child 2 Closed
789     Parent  Closed
789     Child 1 Open
789     Child 2 Closed
```

I return nothing with,

```
select UID from TABLE
where  
(TITLE = 'Parent' and Business = 'Closed') 
and
(TITLE like 'Child%' and Business = 'Open')
```

Comment: FYI, the reason you're not getting any results is because you're asking the database to return records where the 'TITLE' says both 'Parent' and some form of 'Child' (after your edit). None of your rows show that you have a record where the 'TITLE' includes both the names 'Parent' and 'Child' together.

Comment: If you consider such situation an error, you'd want another data model: one main table for UID and business (with UID being the primary key), one detail table for UID and title (with a composite primary key on both columns and UID being the foreign key to the main table).

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate per UID and use `HAVING` to check that records for both conditions exist:

```
select uid
from TABLE
group by uid  
having count(case when title = 'Parent' and business = 'Closed' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when title like 'Child%' and business = 'Open' then 1 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to join the table to itself and then look for the invalid combination:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.UID
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.UID = t2.UID
WHERE t1.Title = 'Parent' AND
      t1.Business = 'Closed' AND
      t2.Title LIKE 'Child%' AND
      t2.Business = 'Open'
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using exists

```
select t1.* from 
table t1
where t1.Title in ('parent','closed')
and not exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.UID=t2.UID  
       and Business='Open' and Title ='Child'  ) 
union 
select * from table 
where Title not in ('parent','closed')
```